# Export animation of grid from blender to XCode

Tags: ios, swift, animation, augmented-reality, blender

I have a grid in blender with a wave modifier added. I have captured (and baked) the animation from frame 20 - 104 selected (because it looks like the wave is endless).

Now I want to export this animation to Xcode to create a AR App (School project).

I've already tried to export it with:

```
File -> Export -> .dae
```

It does export the model, but when I'm trying to view it it only shows a static image. No animation..

The files can be found [here](https://github.com/base2code/blender_to_xcode) (GitHub).

Thank you!